# Kokabiel's History Forgotten?

Tags: canon, book-of-enoch

For those of you who don't know who **Kokabiel** was, Kokabiel was a former advocate of God and his proponents. He was also known as **"The Star of God"** back when he was still an advocate of God and his proponents. He was known as "The Star of God" by many of his peers because he was seen as a paragon of God himself. But then, as the indefinite continued progression of his existence went on some events had changed him completely. To be more specific he eventually became a dissident of God and his followers. So, what made him change and go completely against God and his advocates? Simple. It was due to
an arcane event that took place during his years as a proponent of God. At that time the proponents of God were looking for the **"The Nector of
Immortality"** because they were slowly losing their Immortality due to a curse set by a demon a very long time ago. And it's effects were starting to take place.

The Proponents of God feared that they would lose their powers and hence become weak and mortal.Since, the Universe was just so vast they needed help in locating "The Nector of Immortality". So the Proponents of God turned towards the demons for help. But, you might ask why would the demons help their arch rivals? The Proponents of God manage to convince the demons into assisting them in the search by promising them that they would be given a certain amount of the Nector. Anyways, the demons
and The Proponents of God eventually discover the location of the Nector throught their knowledge and contacts(It is revealed that "The Nector of Immortality" was found at the center of the Universe). The Proponents of God are delighted and relieved of their success. On the Surface everything seems fine.

But, this is when Kokabiel starts to see the corrupt side of some his Superiors and fellow Proponents of God. When the demons ask the Proponents of God for their share of the Nector they are denied of it and the Proponents of Gods start to Mercilessly torture and slaughter the Demons. The Demons do try fight back and defend themselves but they are powerless against the Immortal Proponents of God. The entire demons who took part in that expedition were slaughtered by Kokabiel Superiors. It's is suggested that about 220,000 demons were killed that day.

This was one the events that completely shocked Kokabiel and changed him completely. It is sometime after these events that Kokabiel slowly starts realize the corruption within the Proponents of God and eventually
goes against God and his Proponents. This is why sometimes he is referred by some demons as **"The messiah of the Weak"**.

**My Question is why is Kokabiel not metioned in the Bible or in the Christian Doctrine in general?**

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question doesn't really work here for two reasons: 1) It's not really about Christianity, since this belief forms no part of Christianity, and 2) it's primarily based on opinion, and not something that can be answered objectively. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: That's a lot of story that you could have just linked to.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why [Kokabiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokabiel)'s story is not part of the bible is that it is taken from the [Book of Enoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch), which is not considered as being part of Sacred Scripture by most Christian Churches. The Book of Enoch is recognized as Scripture only in the Ethiopian Orthodox Church and the Eritrean Orthodox Church.